# Find the limit of a recurrence relation

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, analytic-number-theory, analytic-combinatorics

For given a sequence $\{b_k\}_{k\ge1}$, consider the following recurrence relation:
$$
\begin{cases}
u_0=1,\\
u_n=1-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}u_jb_{n-j},\;n=1,2,\dots
\end{cases}
$$
It is known that $0<b_k<1$ for all $k$, and I would like to study $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n$. After some calculations, I feel that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=\left(1+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}b_{j}\right)^{-1}.
$$
But, I don't know how to get a closed form of $u_n$ so as to prove the existence of the limit, or get the limit. Is there any method to study the asymptotic behavior of a recurrence relation? Please give me some help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b_0=1$, and consider $B(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n z^n$ and $U(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_n z^n$ in the [formal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) sense. The recurrence, written as $\sum_{j=0}^{n}u_j b_{n-j}=1$, holds for all $n\geqslant 0$ and implies $B(z)U(z)=(1-z)^{-1}$. Now $B(z)$ can be thought of as a function of $z\in\mathbb{C}$ regular in $|z|<1$ (at least). Thus, $U(z)$ is analytic (its series converges) at least in $|z|<\min\{1,r\}$, where $r=\inf\{|z| : B(z)=0\}$ (if $B(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $B(z)$ converges, we take $r$ to be the radius of convergence).

In particular, if $\color{blue}{r>1}$, then the function $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big(u_n-1/B(1)\big)z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}\left(\frac{1}{B(z)}-\frac{1}{B(1)}\right)$$ is analytic in $|z|<r$; thus, the series is convergent at $z=1$, and your claim $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}u_n=1/B(1)$ holds.

But $r>1$ may well fail to hold. Let $b_{2n}=a^n$ and $b_{2n+1}=b^n$, where $0<a,b<1$. Then $$B(z)=\frac{1}{1-az^2}+\frac{z}{1-bz^2},$$ and we choose $a$ and $b$ so that $B(-r)=0$ for some $r<1$ (this can be done if $r>(\sqrt{5}-1)/2$; say, for $r=2/3$ we can take $a=1/8$ and $b=5/6$). Then $U(z)$ has a pole at $z=-r$, and $|u_n|$ grows like $r^{-n}$. The same applies to $r=1$; we can take $a=b=1/2$ and get $u_n=(-1)^n/2$ for $n>1$.

Still, an interesting question (that I would ask separately) is: what happens if $B(z)$ is analytic and $\neq 0$ in some open set containing $\{z\in\mathbb{C} : |z|\leqslant 1,\ z\neq 1\}$? I could not build a counterexample, but I'm not sure the claim always holds in this case.

Comment: If we assume $b(1)$ is convergent, how do I claim that $r>1$?

Comment: I still don't know how to calculate $r$ in your counted example. Could you please give me more help on $r=\inf\{|z|: b(z) =0\}$ since I am not familiar with complex analysis? Or, could you please give me some reference of this technique? Maybe a book. I really want to learn it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!! I learned a lot from you. Thanks again.

Comment: I went through the claim again and found sth that I couldn't figure it out. I thought $b(z)u(z)=(1-z)^{-1}$ implies that $b(z)$ and $u(z)$ are (at least) regular in $|z|<1$. However, if $r>1$, then the key expression $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big(u_n-1/b(1)\big)z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}\left(\frac{1}{b(z)}-\frac{1}{b(1)}\right)$$ should be regular in $|z|<\min\{1,r\}=1$. If so, how does it yield that the series is convergent at $z=1$??

Comment: @Tony: [Edited it now. So, $z=1$ is a *removable singularity* of the RHS; the limit is $b'(1)/b^2(1)$.]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and derivations. But I am not familiar with complex analysis. I thought that if $r>1$ then $\min\{1,r\}=1$ and $b(1)$ exists. Consequently, $$b(z)u(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}\;\;\mbox{for}\;\;|z|<1$$(since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n}=(1-z)^{-1}$ for $|z|<1$ ), which implies that \begin{align*}u(z)-\frac{1}{b(1)(1-z)}&=\frac{1}{1-z}\left(\frac{1}{b(z)}-\frac{1}{b(1)}\right)\;\;\mbox{for}\;\;|z|<1.\end{align*} How do I obtain that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big(u_n-1/b(1)\big)z^n$ is regular for $|z|<r$ where $r$ has been assumed to be larger than 1?

Comment: Do you mean that $$u(z)-\frac{1}{b(1)(1-z)}=\frac{1}{1-z}\left(\frac{1}{b(z)}-\frac{1}{b(1)}\right)$$ still holds if we know in advance $r>1$?

Comment: @Tony: [chat?] Unfortunately, I'm using [some very basic facts from] complex analysis here. The RHS is regular in $|z|<r$ (as said above, $z=1$ is a removable singularity). Hence it is representable by a power series *that converges there*. But, in $|z|<1$, we have another power series (given by the LHS). Since the power series is unique, these two must coincide.

Comment: Many thanks for your further explanations. If we know $r>1$, then the RHS is regular in $|z|<r$, which implies that $$\lim_{z\to1}\frac{1}{1-z}\left(\frac{1}{b(z)}-\frac{1}{b(1)}\right)=\frac{b'(1)}{b^{2}(1)}\;\;\mbox{by L'Hopital's rule}.$$ Thus, $z=1$ is a removable singularity. Am I right?

Comment: @Tony: I would say "... which is implied by...".

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: What happens if $r=1$ and $b(1)(<\infty)$ exists (implying that $b(z)$ is analytic at $z=1$)? I think the arguments still hold true and yield the same conclusion, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=1/b(1)$.

Comment: @Tony: The arguments fail for, say, $b(z)=2-\sqrt{1-z}$ (the "$2$" to have $b_0=1$), when $$\frac{1}{1-z}\left(\frac{1}{b(z)}-\frac{1}{b(1)}\right)=\frac{1}{2(3+z)}\left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-z}}\right)$$ has a singularity at $z=1$, but this doesn't prevent *the conclusion* to hold. I still have to think it through. I'm not sure if it's time to ask a separate question (the topic is still the same...).

Comment: Thank you so much. The $b(z)=2-\sqrt{1-z}$ is a nice example. By the way, you can, of course, update the answer and (delete or revise) your comments.

Comment: @Tony: Stumbled on [this](https://old.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1949-01.pdf), seems closely related.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.